# window function on a subset of data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table like the below. I want to calculate an average of median but only for Q=2 and Q=3. I don't want to include other Qs but still preserve the data.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2018-03-31',6,1),('2018-03-31',27,2),('2018-03-31',3,3),('2018-03-31',44,4),('2018-06-30',6,1),('2018-06-30',4,3),('2018-06-30',32,2),('2018-06-30',112,4),('2018-09-30',2,1),('2018-09-30',23,4),('2018-09-30',37,3),('2018-09-30',3,2)],['date','median','Q'])
```

```
+----------+--------+---+
|      date| median | Q |
+----------+--------+---+
|2018-03-31|       6|  1|
|2018-03-31|      27|  2|
|2018-03-31|       3|  3|
|2018-03-31|      44|  4|
|2018-06-30|       6|  1|
|2018-06-30|       4|  3|
|2018-06-30|      32|  2|
|2018-06-30|     112|  4|
|2018-09-30|       2|  1|
|2018-09-30|      23|  4|
|2018-09-30|      37|  3|
|2018-09-30|       3|  2|
+----------+--------+---+
```

Expected output:

```
+----------+--------+---+------------+
|      date| median | Q |result      |
+----------+--------+---+------------+
|2018-03-31|       6|  1|        null|
|2018-03-31|      27|  2|          15|
|2018-03-31|       3|  3|          15|
|2018-03-31|      44|  4|        null|
|2018-06-30|       6|  1|        null|
|2018-06-30|       4|  3|          18|
|2018-06-30|      32|  2|          18|
|2018-06-30|     112|  4|        null|
|2018-09-30|       2|  1|        null|
|2018-09-30|      23|  4|        null|
|2018-09-30|      37|  3|          20|
|2018-09-30|       3|  2|          20|
+----------+--------+---+------------+
```

OR

```
+----------+--------+---+------------+
|      date| median | Q |result      |
+----------+--------+---+------------+
|2018-03-31|       6|  1|          15|
|2018-03-31|      27|  2|          15|
|2018-03-31|       3|  3|          15|
|2018-03-31|      44|  4|          15|
|2018-06-30|       6|  1|          18|
|2018-06-30|       4|  3|          18|
|2018-06-30|      32|  2|          18|
|2018-06-30|     112|  4|          18|
|2018-09-30|       2|  1|          20|
|2018-09-30|      23|  4|          20|
|2018-09-30|      37|  3|          20|
|2018-09-30|       3|  2|          20|
+----------+--------+---+------------+
```

I tried the following code but when I include the where statement it drops Q=1 and Q=4.

```py
window = (    
    Window    
    .partitionBy("date")    
    .orderBy("date")    
)   
     
df_avg = (    
    df    
    .where(    
        (F.col("Q") == 2) |    
        (F.col("Q") == 3)    
    )    
    .withColumn("result", F.avg("median").over(window))    
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both of your expected output, you can use conditional aggregation, use `avg` with `when` (`otherwise`).

If you want the 1st expected output.

```py
window = (    
    Window    
    .partitionBy("date", F.col("Q").isin([2, 3]))
)   
     
df_avg = (    
    df.withColumn("result", F.when(F.col("Q").isin([2, 3]), F.avg("median").over(window)))
)
```

For the 2nd expected output.

```py
window = (    
    Window    
    .partitionBy("date")       
) 

df_avg = (
    df.withColumn("result", F.avg(F.when(F.col("Q").isin([2, 3]), F.col("median"))).over(window))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, since you are really aggregating a (small?) subset, replace window with auto-join:

```
>>> df_avg = df.where(col("Q").isin([2,3])).groupBy("date","Q").agg(avg("median").alias("result"))
>>> df_result = df.join(df_avg,["date","Q"],"left")
```

Might turn out to be faster than using `window`.

Comment: Thanks I was actually thinking of similar solution. This was just a slice of data to demo how df is structured. I am now working with roughly 20k rows so probably will stick to window. But definately an interesting solution!